# How to make 1 of 2 stimuli disappear after 1 is replaced?

Tags: psychopy

I am using the Builder view to create a Dot-Probe Task. My task starts with a fixation cross, followed by two words being presented. After 500ms, 1 of the words is replaced by a probe (3mm dot). I created the dot with the "Image" component. My problem is, when the probe appears, it does not replace the verbal stimuli but it is layered on top of it.

Is there a way for the probe to actually replace the verbal stimuli?

I am not sure if it matters, but the location of the probe does switch depending on the frame.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "verbal"? This implies an auditory stimulus, but you also refer to the visual stimulus being "layered" on top of it, implying it is written rather than spoken text?

Comment: Yes, the stimuli I am using are written words. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In the Builder timeline, each component has a specified onset time and offset time. In this case, your text stimulus simply needs to have an offset time 500 ms after its onset time, matching the onset of the probe.

If the stimulus which disappears changes from trial to trial, then you should set the offset time using a variable from your conditions file rather than a fixed value.

But you probably know that already to have gotten this far. So is there more going on than your question currently reveals?

Comment: I did not think of changing the variables in the excel file. I will try that! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I created a variable in my excel file for the written stimuli to have specified offset times. When the probe replaces one of the written stimuli, I still want the second written stimulus to remain. In Builder view, I specified the start time as "time (s)" and the stop as "condition" and put in my variable. For some reason, my written stimuli are not appearing now but the probe does. Any thoughts?

Comment: A condition is an expression that returns a True or False value. The easiest thing to do here would instead be to use time instead and just list actual time values in your Excel sheet, one column for the first word and one for the second. e.g. if #1 disappears then its offset time is 0.5, otherwise it is some large number (or leave blank for an indefinite duration).